# How to turn on promiscous mode in vmware?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation

I was told that in order to turn on promiscous mode in vmware, I need to do this:

```
chmod a+rw /dev/vmnet*
```

However, I am confused that there is an option in the vmfusion preference:

[image]

Do I need to do both in order to use promiscous mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running VMware as root.

As per VMware's guidance:

" If you want all users to be able to set the virtual Ethernet adapter (/dev/vmnet0 in our example) to promiscuous mode, run the following command on the host operating system as root:

chmod a+rw /dev/vmnet0 "

Make sure once you have made the change to virtual adapters in root that you return to a normal user account and disable root account as this has elevated privileges which are not suitable for day to day usage.

Hope this helps